# DD-WRT SSH Setup

Tags: ssh, ip, dd-wrt, wake-on-lan

Okay so I installed DD-WRT firmware onto my Linksys E2000. I can see my dd-wrt page and everything but I am having trouble setting up ssh usage. I tried following [these instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVOxc.jpg). But after all that, I tried ssh'ing from another comp using putty and it just says "Network error: Connection timed out". I'll post pics of my steps here, maybe someone will see something I missed:

From the **Configuring the DD-WRT SSH Server** of the instructions page, here's step #1-6:
[image]

Steps #7-10:
[image]

Then putty:
[image]

I got that IP address, by googling "What's my IP" on the machine that I want to remotely wake up. Not sure if that is the IP i should be using but I don't see any instructions anywhere telling me otherwise.

Anyway, the ssh'ing is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a static IP address, that IP address you got when you googled it will change.  If you attempted it right after googling your IP address then you probably were inside your LAN when you attempted to login.

You have SSH setup from within your LAN on port 22 (the default).  So Putty should be set up using port 22 if you used a LAN IP address.  But since you used your external IP address (the one that shows up when you googled "What is my IP address") your DD-WRT setup is port 443 for external SSH connections.

To test your setup, google your IP address again, and change the port to 443 on PuTTy.  If it works, then you just have to look into a Dynamic DNS service (ie. dyn.com) to enable you to connect after your ISP changes your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the router's internal IP to reach the SSH server from anywhere inside your network, i.e. 192.168.0.1 or similar.

Also, for the WOL to work, you don't SSH into the machine you want to WOL, but the router, and then tell the router to send a WOL packet to whatever machine you want to wake up.  Probably done easier by enabling remote management and through the web interface.

Comment: are there any tutorials I can follow? I'm pretty new to all this stuff.